# Would spontaneous electron excitation be biologically dangerous?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, magic, physics

I am considering a setting where an all-permeating "background magic field" has a side-effect of randomly bumping electrons of any contained matter into an excited state (let's say it can provide up to about 3 eV of energy per "bump", at an average rate of 100 bumps per millisecond per cubic micrometer).

Would this be dangerous to the living organisms present in such a field?

I imagine this would at least affect photosensitive molecules in the eyes, which is probably not going to be very comfortable. But I don't know enough about biology to predict if there would be some more detrimental consequences.

My motivation with this is mainly to justify "constantly glowing" crystals, with the luminescence intensity depending on the strength of magic in a particular area (that's how I chose my ballpark estimates for the energy and rate, though it's likely not bright enough or too dangerous for the best-case scenario). But even if glowing crystals can be justified in other ways, I'm still curious about the biological (un)safety of the idea described above.

---

(Edits: reformulated the question to be about a specific effect)

Comment: magic is magic, you define how it works. but glowing natural crystals would be not harmless nor harmful, they would likely be beneficial. A regular source of light in caves could create much more diverse cave ecosystems. especially once microscopic plants start growing or stealing such crystals, think land coral.

Comment: You have two questions there: "is it possible" and "if it's possible, what are the side effects". Can you limit yourself to one, please?

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question to more clearly state that I'm asking about the harmlessness of the described cause of luminescence, not the glowing crystals themselves, and removed the question about the side-effects.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact I reformulated the question. Does it now meet the criteria you outlined?

Comment: That is a lot better. Specific and answerable. Thanks. I've retracted my close vote and encourage others to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Comparison with light

3 eV correspond to the energy of a photon with a wavelength of 413 nm, which in turn is violet light.
Exposure to sunlight (more precisely the violet portion of it) corresponds to roughly 10⁸ such events per square micrometre per second¹. Your effect would yield 10⁵ events per cubic micrometre per second. If sunlight homogeneously penetrated the first millimetre of skin, this would be equivalent to your effect.

This I expect this to be acceptable in terms of cancer, unless your effect tends has a higher propensity for DNA-alteration than regular light.
However, since the entire body is affected, other types of cancer may get as frequent as skin cancer.
Also, I don’t know how well skin absorption protects us from such effects.

---

¹ Going by [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_spectrum_en.svg) the irradiation of sunlight corresponds to $I=1\frac{\text{W}}{\text{m}^2 \text{nm}}$ in that wave length. If we look at a wave-length window of $Δλ = 50\,\text{nm}$ (roughly the width of what we call *violet*) and consider an area of $A= (1 \text{μm})^2$, we get for an energy $E=3\,\text{eV}$:
$$ n = \frac{I·A·Δλ}{E} ≈ 10^8\,\text{Hz}$$

#### Total energy deposited

The [average human metabolic rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_power#Available_power) is about 80 W.
This alone causes our body temperature to be 37°C in an environment of 20°C.
Your effect on the other hand would dispose about 1 kW in the average human².
This is twelve times that amount and corresponds to the power output of a human during bursts of hard physical exercise (e.g., a sprint or similar), which can be upheld for only about a minute.

The human body has cooling mechanisms that allow it to maintain its body temperature after such bursts such as sweating, but I strongly doubt that these mechanisms can work permanently.
Humans would have to sweat and drink a lot or use other means to cool their bodies.
And that’s not even accounting for the fact that our entire environment would be heated up in a similar manner too.

---

² The average human has a volume of $V_\text{h}=60\,\text{ℓ}$. You deposit $E=3\,\text{eV}$ with a rate of $f=10^5\,\text{Hz}$ in $V=(1\,\text{μm})^3$, yielding a power of:

$$ P = f \frac{V_\text{h}}{V} E = 960\,\text{W}$$

Answer (score 4):

**This is like fluorescent bulbs glowing in an alternating magnetic field.**

[image: bulb in field]

https://www.farmanddairy.com/top-stories/how-to-make-a-fluorescent-bulb-glow-under-transmission-power-lines/623730.html

> When you take a fluorescent tube bulb under transmission power lines
> it lights up because the current running through them induces an
> alternating magnetic field around them as they conduct electricity.
> The higher the voltage, the greater the magnetic field density and the
> brighter the fluorescent tube will glow.

So there is precedent.  Your magic field excites the crystals and makes them glow.  The glow is work and so the presence of these crystals reduces the power of the magic field, if that matters.  The fluorescent bulb also slightly reduces the power of the transmission line.

You could make the crystals a little bit hazardous if the spectrum they glow in is not limited to the visible.  Maybe you could get sunburned next to one.

---

Maybe they are also glowing in radio waves.  But it is not glowing.  It is talking.  If you have an antenna you might be able to hear what they are saying.  You might have an antenna and not know that what you have is an antenna.

Answer (score 2):

3ev is bordering ultraviolet from the visible side - 3eV is 418nm wavelength, within the "violet" range. Ultraviolet starts at about 400nm, some even consider it to start at 380nm (3.25eV).

It should be fine, maybe the vampires may get a mild sunburn but won't die of it.